# How does the use of my Mongo DB server work in the context of a program with it that is downloaded by a user?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, user-interface, web-scraping

I am making a program that allows a user to generate a random anime from a given genre, where the data was scraped from MyAnimeList and stored in a database on my MongoDB server. The program currently has 3 files. anime.py scrapes anime information from MyAnimeList.net and saves them as objects. anime_database.py essentially takes those objects and stores them as documents in the collection 'animes' in a database on my Mongo DB server 'anime_db'. Then I have a gui.py which takes the data I wish to display from my documents whenever a user wants to generate a random anime from a given genre in a drop down menu. The code I have so far is shown below:

anime.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from termcolor import colored
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

class Anime:
    def __init__(self, rank, title, score, genres, image_link):
        self.rank = rank
        self.title = title
        self.score = score
        self.genres = genres
        self.image_link = image_link

    def display_details(self):
        print(f"Rank: {self.rank}")
        print(f"Title: {self.title}")
        print(f"Score: {self.score}")
        print(f"Genres: {','.join(self.genres)}")
        print(f"Image Link: {self.image_link}")

    @staticmethod
    # Scrapes all wanted data from each anime on a page and makes an object for each anime
    def scrape_from_myanimelist():
        score = 10
        base_url = "https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php"
        url_list = []
        anime_objects = []
        limit_num = 0
        num = 0

        user_agent = UserAgent()
        random_agent = user_agent.random
        headers = {'User-Agent': random_agent}

        while float(score) >= 8.00:
            # Takes all individual anime pages from each myanimelist top anime page
            try:
                url_list.append(base_url)
                html = requests.get(url_list[-1], headers=headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
                animes_links = soup.find_all('h3', class_='fl-l fs14 fw-b anime_ranking_h3')
                href_list = []
                for link in animes_links:
                        link_tag = link.find('a')
                        if link_tag:
                                href = link_tag.get('href')
                                href_list.append(href)
            except:
                print('HTML structure likely changed on top anime page')
                
            time.sleep(3)


            # Scrapes wanted data from each anime page
            for url in href_list:
                    html = requests.get(url)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
                    score = soup.find(itemprop='ratingValue').text
                    if float(score) < 8.00:
                        break
                    title = soup.find('h1').text
                    ranked = soup.find('span', class_='numbers ranked')
                    rank = ranked.find('strong').text
                    rank = rank[1:]
                    genres = soup.find_all(itemprop='genre')
                    genre_list = []
                    for genre in genres:
                            genre_list.append(genre.text)
                    image_link = soup.find(itemprop='image')['data-src']
                    anime_obj = Anime(rank, title, score, genre_list, image_link)
                    anime_objects.append(anime_obj)
                    num = num + 1
                    print(rank)
                    print(title)
                    print(score)
                    print(genre_list)
                    print(image_link)
                    time.sleep(3)
            limit_num += 50
            base_url = 'https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php' + f'?limit={limit_num}'
            colored_text = colored(f'{num} objects have been created', 'red', attrs=['bold'])
            print(colored('-' * 40, 'white'))
            print(colored_text)
            print(colored('-' * 40, 'white'))


        return anime_objects
```

anime_database.py

```
import pymongo
from anime import Anime
from termcolor import colored
from random import choice

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['anime_db']
collection = db['animes']

def insert_anime_objects(anime_objects):
    inserted_check = 0
    for anime_obj in anime_objects:
        doc = {

        'rank': anime_obj.rank,
        'title': anime_obj.title,
        'score': anime_obj.score,
        'genres': anime_obj.genres,
        'image link' : anime_obj.image_link

        }

        verify = collection.find_one({'title': anime_obj.title})

        if verify is None:
            collection.insert_one(doc)
            inserted_check += 1

    colored_text = colored(f'{inserted_check} have been inputted', 'red', attrs=['bold'])
    print(colored_text)
    print(colored('-' * 40, 'white'))

def get_anime_by_genre(genre):
    query = {'genres': genre}
    animes = list(collection.find(query))
    random_anime = choice(animes)
    return random_anime

def update_database():
    anime_list = Anime.scrape_from_myanimelist()
    insert_anime_objects(anime_list)
    color_text = colored('Database Insertion Complete', 'red', 'on_green')
    print(color_text)
```

gui.py

```
from random import choice
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, Label, Frame
import anime_database as my_database
import pymongo
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests
import io

genre_list = ['Action','Adventure','Avant Garde','Award Winning','Boys Love','Comedy',
                  'Drama','Fantasy','Girls Love','Gourmet','Horror','Mystery','Romance',
                  'Sci-Fi','Slice of Life','Sports','Supernatural','Suspense','Ecchi',
                  'Erotica','Hentai','Adult Cast', 'Anthropomorphic','CGDCT','Childcare',
                  'Combat Sports','Crossdressing','Delinquents','Detective','Educational',
                  'Gag Humor','Gore','Harem','High Stakes Game','Historical','Idols (Female)',
                  'Idols (Male)','Isekai','Iyashikei','Love Polygon','Magical Sex Shift',
                  'Mahou Shoujo','Martial Arts','Mecha','Medical','Military','Music','Mythology',
                  'Organized Crime','Otaku Culture','Parody','Performing Arts','Pets',
                  'Psychological','Racing','Reincarnation','Reverse Harem','Romantic Subtext',
                  'Samurai','School','Showbiz','Space','Strategy Game','Super Power','Survival',
                  'Team Sports','Time Travel','Vampire','Video Game','Visual Arts','Workplace']

class AnimeChooserApp:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("Anime Chooser")
        root.maxsize(900,600)
        self.root.config(bg="skyblue")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.left_frame = Frame(self.root, width=200, height=400, bg='grey')
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        self.right_frame = Frame(self.root, width=650, height=400,bg='skyblue')
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        genre_label = Label(self.left_frame, text = "Select Genre:")
        genre_label.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.genre_var = tk.StringVar()
        genre_combo = ttk.Combobox(self.left_frame, textvariable=self.genre_var, state='readonly', values=genre_list)
        genre_combo.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.label = Label(self.right_frame, text='',bg='skyblue')
        self.label.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.image_label = Label(self.right_frame,bg='skyblue')
        self.image_label.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.label2 = Label(self.left_frame,bg='grey')
        self.label2.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.label3 = Label(self.left_frame,bg='grey')
        self.label3.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.label4 = Label(self.left_frame,bg='grey')
        self.label4.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        random_anime_button = ttk.Button(self.left_frame,text='Generate Anime',command=self.anime_choice).grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

    def anime_choice(self):
        selected_genre = self.genre_var.get()
        random_anime = my_database.get_anime_by_genre(selected_genre)

        self.label.config(text=random_anime['title'],bg='white')
        self.label2.config(text=f'Rank: {random_anime["rank"]}',bg='white')
        self.label3.config(text=f'Score: {random_anime["score"]}',bg='white')
        seperator = "\n"
        result_string = seperator.join(random_anime["genres"])
        self.label4.config(text=f'Genres: \n{result_string}',bg='white')

        image_url = random_anime['image link']
        response = requests.get(image_url)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            image_data = io.BytesIO(response.content)
            img = Image.open(image_data)
            img = img.resize((400,500))
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            
            if self.image_label:
                self.image_label.config(image=img)
                self.image_label.image = img
            else:
                self.image_label = Label(self.right_frame, image=img)
                self.image_label.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        else:
            print(f'Failed to retrieved image from URL: {image_url}')       

    def confirm_exit(self):
        result = messagebox.askyesno("Confirmation", "Are you sure you want to exit?")
        if result:
            self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AnimeChooserApp(root)
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', app.confirm_exit)
    root.mainloop()
```

[Image of my GUI rough draft if interested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jSbi.png)

This is my first real project and it still has a lot of development left and theres some bugs if a less popular genre is picked which I will fix soon. My real concern is that even though I am sure that I can get the program running perfectly on my end, I am confused on how to get this to be an end product that a user could download from github and actually use for themselves. Right now, the data to be displayed is being retrieved from my mongo db server, which im not sure if when the user downloads the program, the connection will actually work for them since the server is running on my laptop. There is also the concern of how they will be able to run this like any normal program from clicking an icon on their desktop and everything loading for them rather than needing to run the python files through the terminal. If anyone can just point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Again, I am  still a beginner so please do not assume I know what may seem obvious to most programmers. Thank you for your time.

I have tried running this from my own terminal but I wish to make this a program that can be downloaded from github by a user. I have tried pyinstaller which I've heard could make my program into an exe file that others can download to their device but the file would not open when I tried to run it. I am assuming this is because of something obvious that can be seen in the way this program is structured so far. If not, I will probably make a question post for that too.